# View Switch COM exception unity uwp c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I have a Unity HoloLens UWP application that switches between a 2D and 3D view. It works fine on HoloLens emulator version 10.0.14393.1358 but not on 10.0.17134.80.

On the newer version I get the following exception and stack trace:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)  
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()  
    at AppViewInfo.<<SwitchAsync>b__10_0>d.MoveNext()"
```

The code where this occurs is as follows:

```
public async Task SwitchAsync()
{
    await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(this.view.Id); //<---EXCEPTION
    });
}
```

Any help getting to the bottom of this seemingly cryptic COM exception is greatly appreciated. I've seen a couple posts indicating that this may be related to background app privacy settings. However, I don't see an option to change that on the HoloLens.

Comment: Could you share more about `this.view.Id` parameter?

Comment: First, I create a new view using view = CoreApplication.CreateNewView(). Then I use the dispatcher from this returned view to store the final ApplicationView object as ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView(). That is, that call runs from the created view dispatcher. So, that's where view.Id comes from.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue with your description, please share mini sample that could reproduce this.